# Firebase validation rule not working

Tags: ios, database, swift, firebase, firebase-security

I'm using Firebase & iOS and trying to validate when a user tries to submit a comment.

Here are my rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "comments": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": "auth.uid != null",
      "$comment_id": {
        ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 100"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my database structure:
[image]

The comment that has been posted successfully was when I deleted the `".validate"` portion.  I've also tried putting `".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 100"` outside of the the `$comment_id` block but this still resulted in failure.

Regardless, I get this error from the simulator when I try to add a comment:
[image]

Why isn't my `".validate"` working?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data path is `/comments/$comment_id/comment`. Your validation rule doesn't cater for that last `comment` in there.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "comments": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": "auth.uid != null",
      "$comment_id": {
        "comment": {
          ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 100"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

These rules will work. But I'd probably update the data structure to remove the `comment` node, since it doesn't add any value.